# Ajax script with wordpress is adding a random '0' in my output

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a wordpress plugin that uses ajax to update a div every 10 seconds.

It seems to work and is running the AJAX GET request, and outputs `test` as it should, how ever also adds a `0` to the div output. `(response)`

I cant work out why it is doing it? Any suggestions?

**PHP**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aj_enqueue_scripts' );
function aj_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aj-demo', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'aj-demo-ajax-code.js?v=2', array('jquery') );
    // The second parameter ('aj_ajax_url') will be used in the javascript code.
    wp_localize_script( 'aj-demo', 'aj_ajax_demo', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'aj_demo_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('aj-demo-nonce') 
    ));
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_aj_ajax_demo_get_count', 'aj_ajax_demo_process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_aj_ajax_demo_get_count', 'aj_ajax_demo_process' );  // For 

function aj_ajax_demo_process() {
    echo "test";
}
?>
```

**Jquery / JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : aj_ajax_demo.ajax_url, 
            type : 'get',
            data : {
                action : 'aj_ajax_demo_get_count', 
                nonce : aj_ajax_demo.aj_demo_nonce, 
            
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                jQuery('.now_playing_info').html(response);  
            },
            error : function( response ) {
                
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an `exit;` at the end of function.

```php
function aj_ajax_demo_process() {
  echo "test";
  exit; // add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will continue to call all of the AJAX registered callbacks until one of the callbacks kills the execution, with the final one dieing with the response of 0.

So just use `wp_die()` at the end of your code

```
function aj_ajax_demo_process() {
   echo "test";
   wp_die();
}
```